# sharepoint 2010 central administration error 500

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

when i try to open central administration in sharepoint 2010 server it give to me a "Service Unavailable" error with http code 500.

Other sites on my farm are working fine.

any help please.

Comment: Check (in IIS) if central administration application pool is running

Comment: The issue was in web.config in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN. I change it and central administration works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth seeing if any Windows services stopped , e.g SPAdminV4